# ARCore unity debugging

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine, printing, arcore

For example I try to print out to the console and it doesn't, my script is attached to my main camera so we can rule that out and yes the script is active also, any help will be appreciated, right now what I am working on is to click on a certain part of my GameObject in AR and while my phone is connected to the computer I want to see the name of the certain part I clicked on in the console.

Answer (score 3):

When you run the app on and Android device the log does not go to the Unity editor console.  In order to see it you need to open Android Studio and then use the **Logcat** tab to see the device log.

Alternatively, you can run logcat from the command line
`adb logcat`.

More information: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html

Comment: Small addition: Using `adb logcat -s Unity` from the command line lets you only see the output from Unity.

Comment: Thanks you so so so much, you have saved me so much time, it works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

I have worked with ARCore and had the same frustating experience when it comes to debugging.

If you just want console prints, then use Log viewer which can catch and show them on Android too. (https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/log-viewer-12047)

However, because I wanted more control and the ability to test and debug my game logic right inside the editor (without deploying to the phone all the time), I wrote a little plugin that allows me to do just that. This plugin simulates the operation of ARCore inside Unity editor. You can just hit play and ARCore will be simulated for you, so you can freely develop and debug your game logic. Moreover, you can then just build and deploy the project without changing anything, and ARCore will work like normal on your phone.

Using it is very similar to native ARCore, so you will not have much difficulty getting into it. It does not cover ALL features of ARCore yet, but it covers the basics. You can still use native ARCore for the rest.

You can find it here: https://github.com/VR-House/Eazy-ARCore-Interface

Answer (score 0):

In current versions of Unity you can output logs from connected devices to Unity Editor. To do this, build your project in Development Mode and connect the Console to your device.

But I would recommend a more advanced way of testing AR in Editor with a plugin I wrote. I wrote it for my project and decided to make it into a plugin so everyone else can benefit from it.

AR Foundation Editor Remote plugin:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/ar-foundation-editor-remote-test-and-debug-your-ar-project-in-the-editor.898433/

Answer (score 0):

I use debugging like this in C# script:

```
Debug.Log("Debug message and image name "+Image.Name);
```

To see this real time, I use Android Device Monitor (it's in Android's sdk folder, usually \Users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\monitor.bat. If device is connected, it appears on the devices list and it can be selected.

Or if I want to see the debug log in device, I put these lines in script:

```
private void OnGUI()
{
    GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
    style.fontSize = 50;
    GUI.Box(new Rect(350, 0, 500, 500), Image.Name, style);
}
```

The Rect(350,0 is the position, 500,500 is the width and height of rectangle.